# pandas ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'p-'

Tags: python, pandas, geography

So, I have a dataframe with more that 10^6 lines in it and I am just doing a simple conversion of lat (degrees min) to lat (degrees only). Yet there are lines in my frame which have a string "p-" which kills my loop early on. I have tried a few things (below).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r'/home/engr/Documents/SchoolHR/Data/SFSU-Boat/SBE45m/2015/'

allfiles_list = glob.glob(path + "/15*.hex")
allfiles_list = sorted(allfiles_list)
col = ["temp", "conduct", "salinity", "lat", "lon", "hms", "dmy"]
big_frame = pd.DataFrame()

for name in allfiles_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(name, skiprows=12, encoding="latin1", names=col, na_values=0, na_filter=False, engine="c")
    big_frame = big_frame.append(df)

# TODO surgery on columns to convert to float for use on big_frame

# regex \D to remove any non-digit characters -- hms & dmy
big_frame["hms"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
big_frame["dmy"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
big_frame["temp"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='(\D.\=)',value='')
big_frame["conduct"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='(\D.\=)',value='')
big_frame["salinity"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='(\D.\=)',value='')
big_frame["lat"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='[lonat=]',value='')
big_frame["lon"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='[lonat=]',value='')

for index, row in big_frame.iterrows():
if row.lat[-1] == 'N':
    D = float(row.lat[1:3])
    M = float(row.lat[4:10])
    DD = D + float(M/60)
    row.lat = DD
if row.lon[-1] == 'W':
    D1 = float(row.lon[1:4])
    M1 = float(row.lon[5:12])
    DD1 = D1 + float(M1/60)
    row.lon = -DD1
```

the code returns this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'p-'
```

I tried modifying the code by doing this and running the loop on the dataframe:

```
big_frame['lon'] = big_frame.lon.str.replace('p-?' , '')
big_frame['lat'] = big_frame.lat.str.replace('p-?' , '')
big_frame["lat"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='[)]',value='')
big_frame["lon"].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='[)]',value='')
```

but I just receive this instead:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Sample dataset below:

```
t1= 16.8828, c1= 3.59481, s= 27.3995, lat=37 46.985 N, lon=122 15.544 W, hms=143857, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8674, c1= 3.59335, s= 27.3977, lat=37 46.975 N, lon=122 15.523 W, hms=143907, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8441, c1= 3.59179, s= 27.4003, lat=37 46.966 N, lon=122 15.502 W, hms=143917, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8353, c1= 3.59183, s= 27.4066, lat=37 46.956 N, lon=122 15.480 W, hms=143927, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8169, c1= 3.59054, s= 27.4082, lat=37 46.946 N, lon=122 15.459 W, hms=143937, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8018, c1= 3.58917, s= 27.4068, lat=37 46.936 N, lon=122 15.438 W, hms=143947, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8072, c1= 3.59052, s= 27.4147, lat=37 46.926 N, lon=122 15.417 W, hms=143957, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8361, c1= 3.59415, s= 27.4257, lat=37 46.916 N, lon=122 15.396 W, hms=144007, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8612, c1= 3.59678, s= 27.4308, lat=37 46.907 N, lon=122 15.375 W, hms=144017, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8452, c1= 3.59187, s= 27.4002, lat=37 46.898 N, lon=122 15.356 W, hms=144027, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8439, c1= 3.58982, s= 27.3838, lat=37 46.890 N, lon=122 15.337 W, hms=144037, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8328, c1= 3.58865, s= 27.3814, lat=37 46.882 N, lon=122 15.322 W, hms=144047, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8257, c1= 3.58841, s= 27.3842, lat=37 46.874 N, lon=122 15.307 W, hms=144057, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8165, c1= 3.58856, s= 27.3917, lat=37 46.866 N, lon=122 15.292 W, hms=144107, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8103, c1= 3.58836, s= 27.3942, lat=37 46.858 N, lon=122 15.277 W, hms=144117, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8400, c1= 3.58819, s= 27.3726, lat=37 46.850 N, lon=122 15.263 W, hms=144127, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8547, c1= 3.58945, s= 27.3733, lat=37 46.841 N, lon=122 15.249 W, hms=144137, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8784, c1= 3.59235, s= 27.3817, lat=37 46.833 N, lon=122 15.235 W, hms=144147, dmy=170315
t1= 16.8817, c1= 3.59347, s= 27.3889, lat=37 46.825 N, lon=122 15.221 W, hms=144157, dmy=170315
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the offending rows with something like:

```
big_frame =big_frame[big_frame['col_name'].apply(lambda x: x.isdigit())]
```

And then the action should not fail.

Comment: if you don't care about the reason for the failure and you ignore rows with problems, just wrap in a `try:  except`

Comment: Not sure you could wrap the original code in a try except and have the conversions complete- is that what you're saying?

Comment: I need the last character in the string for the loop to detect the direction of latitude or longitude. That is smart but it wouldn't help. The string is also 'nnn nn.nnn L'. It would error because of the space between the "nnn nn.nnn"

Comment: @ShpielMeister can you give an example? I tried error handling yet it is not skipping the offending rows. How should I call out the corrupted rows?